# Enable Widget Setting button for widgets in Android?

Tags: android, android-widget

Samsung One UI Home Screen shows a setting button for some widgets when I select the widget,

[image]

But not for some

[image]

Wondering what is the difference between the two or is it just a OEM specific feature as I couldn't the menu in POCO launcher or emulator's launcher at all.

Please note I am already using

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:configure=".WidgetConfigurationActivity"
    ...
```

in my provider and this in my manifest

```
        <receiver ...>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>
        ...
```

Yet these are just adding configuration when I add a widget not after the addition of the widget, and couldn't find the answer on searching the net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this question is months old, but I'll answer anyway. After reverse-engineering a Samsung app, I've found the secret behind the Settings button.

You only got to add this meta-data to your app widget (`<receiver>`):

```
<meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider.semConfigureActivity" android:value="com.example.MySettingsActivity" />
```

Full example:

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.MyWidget">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"/>
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider" android:resource="@xml/widget_info"/>
    
    <!-- The secret sauce is here -->
    <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider.semConfigureActivity" android:value="com.example.MySettings"/>
</receiver>
```

**Advice:** It's recommended to learn reverse-engineering to implement undocumented features (just make sure the core functionality of your app does not depend on undocumented APIs).

Comment: Wow, just tested it and added it to the app https://github.com/persian-calendar/DroidPersianCalendar/commit/cd9044a15 , that's so coool! Thanks!!!

Comment: @EbrahimByagowi No problem, I'd recommend to learn reverse-engineering, it's a useful skill.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add also, in Android 12 this has standardized finally and provided with `android:widgetFeatures="reconfigurable"` or (`reconfigurable|configuration_optional`), see https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/configuration#use-default for more information from Android 12.

Also maybe worth to note, apparently `reconfigurable` has been defined for some releases just that in this release the declared it as officially supported.